# Finding all dataframe indices where logical equation is satisfied given two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have to dataframes that I am trying to relate together and find out some info:

df1

```
Name    Logic
Ford    AAA|BBB
Chevy   JJJ|FFF&DDD|AAA|LLL
Porsche FFF&TTT&UUU|OOO|BBB
```

df2

```
idx    AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD   JJJ   FFF   LLL   TTT   UUU   OOO
7T1    True  True  True  False True  True  False True  True  False
8F4    False True  True  False True  False False False True  False
4Q2    True  True  True  True  False True  True  False False True
3Y7    False False False False True  False True  True  True  False
```

I am trying to find every single index value that satisfies each equation in df1 and put them into a new column containing a list. Both dataframes will have many more entries but for sanity's sake I kept them short.

The result df:

```
Name    Logic                       Solutions
Ford    AAA|BBB                 ['7T1','8F4','4Q2']
Chevy   JJJ|FFF&DDD|AAA|LLL     ['7T1','8F4','4Q2','3Y7']
Porsche FFF&TTT&UUU             ['7T1']
```

Comment: Your Porsche logic isn't returning your expected result set.

Comment: They are currently strings. Will re-evaluate and update the asked question @ScottBoston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try using `query`, note this works because of the "simple" column naming, if your columns contains spaces or special characters using `query` with f-string will not work.  Also, this requires python 3.6+:

```
df1['Solutions'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.query(f"{x['Logic']}")
                                          .index.to_series()
                                          .unique(), 
                             axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      Name                Logic             Solutions
0     Ford              AAA|BBB       [7T1, 8F4, 4Q2]
1    Chevy  JJJ|FFF&DDD|AAA|LLL  [7T1, 8F4, 4Q2, 3Y7]
2  Porsche          FFF&TTT&UUU                 [7T1]
```

Comment: I am getting the error `ValueError: ('unknwon type object', 'occurreed at index 0')` which I figured was to column name issues but after cleaning it all up the error remains..still doing some debugging

Comment: Maybe one of your conditions doesn't have a column in the dataframe.  Such as 'ZZZ|BBB' and there is no 'ZZZ' column.

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to be the case. Would there be any issues with pandas version?

Comment: Can you paste a dataset this error happens?  Does it happen with the current dataset?

Comment: I can't post the exact data that I am using. I'm curious, is the `Logic` column type `str`? In my data it is supposed to just be one big string. I'm using an even simpler dataset for `Logic` than this and have verified that every single element of `Logic` exists as a column in df2.

Comment: Hrm... Yes, Logic is str dtype.  Does this code work for you on this small dataset posed in this question?

Comment: OK I constructed the exact ex above and get `Recursion Error: ('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object','ocurred at index 0')`Question: There will always be more column names in the df2 than expressions in df1['Logic'], could this be the error since they aren't always 1:1?

Comment: @MaxB You can test this by hard coding your `df2.query('<hardcode string here>').

Comment: even trying `df2.query('LLL|UUU')` hits the recursion limit

Comment: @MaxB now that is intesting.  df2['LLL'] and df2['UUU'] are dtypes are boolean?

Comment: Can you share your df2?

Comment: My df2 is the exact same as above. Also when running `df2.eval('LLL|UUU')` I get `maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__`

Comment: What dos df2.info() output?

Comment: `Index: 4 entries, 7T1 to 3Y7
Data columns (total 10 columns):
AAA 4 non-null object
....etc
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 352.0+ bytes`

Comment: Yes, that is it is probably the dtype of df2.

Comment: As a test, try this statement.  `df2c.astype('bool').eval('LLL|UUU')`

Comment: If that works, you can either cast your dataframe as bool or add `astype('bool')` in your command. `df2 = df2.astype('bool')` changes those string dtype columns to boolean dtype.  Then try the above solution.

Comment: Success! The real data works too, it was all due to the dtype :P

Comment: @MaxB Awesome!  Happy Coding.